# Is it possible to install x11 without pulling in hundreds of other packages?

Tags: dependencies, x11, rpm, opensuse, xterm

I'm sure this is a stupid question, but I'm going to ask anyway.
Is it possible to install the xterm and xorg-x11-fonts packages on an OpenSuSE machine without pulling in a ton of other packages that it seems to depend on? Is everything in that host of packages truly needed? If not, then what I'd like to know is how to trim that list down and still have a functional Xterm. (Like maybe picking a package several levels down and forcing it to install without some of its dependencies).

Comment: You should end up with a dozen or so packages - not "a ton".  Those would include the libraries (but not the server).

Comment: Just how many packages is it? Including a list might be helpful here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you were using one of the Red Hat-based distributions, then the usual response would be to show how to use `yum` to find the dependencies.  OpenSUSE does not use `yum`, but provides a similar tool `zypper`.

As noted, a list would be helpful.  If I run

```
zypper search --requires xterm
```

there are only a dozen or so packages shown:

```
S | Name                            | Summary
--+---------------------------------+------------------------------------------------
i | codelite                        | Powerful open-source, cross platform code editor
  | eaglemode                       | Eagle Mode the deep application Cosmos
  | leechcraft-shaitan              | LeechCraft Shaitan Module
i | lxterminal-lang                 | Languages for package lxterminal
  | package-lists-openSUSE-GNOME-cd | Patterns for Installation (full ftp tree)
  | package-lists-openSUSE-KDE-cd   | Patterns for Installation (full ftp tree)
  | package-lists-openSUSE-X11-cd   | Patterns for Installation (full ftp tree)
  | package-lists-openSUSE-images   | Patterns for Installation (full ftp tree)
i | xdg-menu                        | XDG Menus for WindowMaker and other Window Manager
i | xdm                             | X Display Manager
i | xinit                           | X Window System initializer
i | xterm                           | X terminal emulator (development version)
```

But the same command for `xorg-x11-fonts` shows me more than 200 packages, including `xorg-x11-server`.

However, looking at the dependencies in this manner only gives one aspect to the story: it shows the effect of *removing* a given package.  The actual question being asked is: what packages will be *added* as a side-effect of adding those two packages.  That list will generally be shorter (usually *much* shorter) than that shown by the `--requires` option.

For instance, if you really only want `xterm` to be available on a machine so that you could `ssh` into a server and run `xterm` on your local machine, you do not need an X server on the *remote* machine.  What would be needed would be the fonts as well as the runtime libraries used by `xterm`.  You can get a (cruder) picture of what those libraries are using

```
rpm -qR xterm
```

for example:

```
/bin/bash
/bin/sh
/bin/sh
/bin/sh
aaa_base
libICE.so.6()(64bit)
libX11.so.6()(64bit)
libXaw.so.7()(64bit)
libXft.so.2()(64bit)
libXmu.so.6()(64bit)
libXpm.so.4()(64bit)
libXt.so.6()(64bit)
libc.so.6()(64bit)
libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.11)(64bit)
libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.14)(64bit)
libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.15)(64bit)
libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.2.5)(64bit)
libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.3)(64bit)
libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.3.4)(64bit)
libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.4)(64bit)
libfontconfig.so.1()(64bit)
libtinfo.so.5()(64bit)
libutempter.so.0()(64bit)
luit
perl
rpmlib(CompressedFileNames) <= 3.0.4-1
rpmlib(PayloadFilesHavePrefix) <= 4.0-1
rpmlib(PayloadIsLzma) <= 4.4.6-1
```

Those are the direct *file* dependencies of the `xterm` package.  You may notice some apparent repeats in the list due to the way `rpm` tracks dependencies.  But a dozen or so packages (some *already* installed) is what that list amounts to.

It is possible to write a script which asks `zypper --provides` for each file and get a list of packages which would be pulled in by installing `xterm` on a bare bones server.  That will give a first approximation to the final list.  However, this will not show packages which must be installed as a side-effect.  Going past that is harder — and that is what `zypper` is for.

If you are starting from a configuration which does not have `xterm` installed, it is simpler to ask `zypper` to install the `xterm` package (to get the *short* list of added packages), and then cancel the install.

Answer (score -1):

You might be able to do this if you spend enough time sorting out what the dependencies are at each step of the way.

That being said I don't expect this to be a simple process or necessarily even a fruitful one. It will also end up in a potentially confusing and confused state at a later date should dependencies change. You will also need to maintain this block going forward as future upgrades will likely pull the skipped packages in.

This is also generally just not a great approach to things. If you are really interested in keeping dependencies down you might be better off trying to build xterm from source yourself (though again that might not actually help much).

Comment: Thanks. That is basically what I was expecting to hear. I was just hoping I was wrong.

Comment: Building xterm from source will not solve the OPs problem, rather it will aggravate it by making it harder to do system updates and keep from breaking his xterm configuration.

Comment: @ThomasDickey My point, though I failed to explain it at all well there, was that it might be possible to opt-out of certain dependencies if he were to build it himself. Dependencies that the distribution provided package have opted in to.